# detection of device type from user agent in adobe analytics raw data

Tags: adobe, adobe-analytics

We are using Adobe Analytics Data Feeds and loading the files into our DataWarehouse.  We have encountered an issue where 'mobiledevice' field does not contain any data. When we questioned Adobe Client care about the issue, we were informed that we needed to choose to either receive user-agent or mobiledevice.  We really don’t want to lose the user-agent data, but we also need to know if our visitors are using a Mobile / Desktop / Tablet device.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Adobe partners with DeviceAtlas to obtain device type from the collected user agent. The data is proprietary to DeviceAtlas, however you could potentially use their services within your own organization.

Comment: After paying so much to Adobe's license per year, it pains to see we need to pay another company just to get to know the device type from the logs. After all it's our data, & For a big company like Adobe and all major companies using it for analytics, they could probably make a deal/buy out the company DeviceAtlas.